# how to upgrade node.js from 4.2 to 6.11.0 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade

Currently, in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, the installed version of Node.Js is 4.2. I want to upgrade it to the current LTS version 6.11.0.
Should I run the following codes for this task:

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

and then

```
sudo n latest
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These commands did the job for me:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 6.11.0
```

Comment: Just to improve a little bit more this answer, with "n" you can install any node version, so if you want the 8.6.0 version just type : "sudo n 8.6.0" instead "sudo n 6.11.0".
Finally restart the machine, to apply changes

Comment: why cache clean require to upgrade node ? @Zanna

Comment: @151291 no idea - I've never used this software, I just fixed the post formatting

Answer (score 0):

to install the latest version using PPA just run:

```
cd ~

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

all instructions are here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/dimitris/.config
```